# How to get larger decimal no. in two array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know How I can get first and second larger decimal no. in array in PHP.
Like :

```
$a = 0.24;
$b = 0.45;
$c = 0.50;
$d = 0.30;

$large = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
```

How I can do this, Or Which function I need to use ?

Thanks !

Comment: I can't see multiple array here. What is your expected output ?

Comment: I want to get first and second larger decimal no. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to retrieve the first and second largest values from an array, just use `rsort()`:

```
$numbers = array(0.90, 0.30, 0.20, 0.50);
rsort($numbers);
```

`$numbers` will now contain an array sorted from highest to lowest, and you will be able to access the values like this:

```
$highest = $numbers[0];
$secondHighest = $numbers[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this .... number_format with your variable

```
$large = array(number_format($a,2),number_format($b,2),number_format($c,2),number_format($d,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `max($array)`;

```
$large = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
$result = max($large);

var_dump($result);
```

This gives:

```
float 0.5
```

To get the first and second largest elements you need to sort the array. `asort` sorts the array in ascending order of the values. The first and the second largest numbers are the two numbers at the rightmost end of the array. `array_pop` removes the element at the end of the array. The first `array_pop` removes the largest and second `array_pop` removes the second largest.

like

```
 $large = array($a,$b,$c,$d);

asort($large);

$largest = array_pop($large);

$second_largest = array_pop($large);

echo "largest = ".$largest;

echo "second_largest = ".$second_largest;
```

This gives:

```
largest = 0.5
second_largest = 0.45
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your requirement.If you need get larger decimal no. in array or largest number from all the multiple array?
If you need to **get max value from each array** you can use max function.
[max()](https://www.php.net/max) returns the numerically highest of the parameter values. If multiple values can be considered of the same size, the one that is listed first will be returned.

**When max() is given multiple arrays, the longest array is returned.** If all the arrays have the same length, max() will use lexicographic ordering to find the return value.

When given a string it will be cast as an integer when comparing.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want first and second larger decimal no. in array .

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ...

```
$large = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
rsort($large);
print_r($large);
```

**Applicable sort functions:**

```
sort
rsort
asort
arsort
natsort
natcasesort
ksort
krsort
```

You can also see this link

[How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

this is very helpful for all of us